# Prove $(bab^{-1})^n = ba^nb^{-1}$ by induction

Tags: induction

p(1): $(bab^{-1})^1 = ba^1b^{-1}.$

p(k + 1): $(bab^{-1})^{k + 1} = (bab^{-1})^k(bab^{-1}) = b^ka^kb^{-k}bab^{-1} = ba^{k + 1}b^{-1}.$

Would that work?

Comment: You have a grave typo or miscalculation.  $(bab^{-1})^k = b^1 a^k b^{-1}\neq b^k a^k b^{-k}$.  Your induction hypothesis should be what you are trying to prove.  It also helps to explicitly state what the induction hypothesis is and where you use it during the algebraic manipulation of the $(k+1)^{st}$ case.

Comment: @ JMoravitz, is $(bab^{-1})^k = a^k?$

Comment: not quite $(bab^{-1})^k = ba^kb^{-1}$, which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Can you, please explain the algebra behind $(bab^{-1})^k = ba^kb^{-1}?$ I don't get it.

Comment: the purpose of the question is to prove exactly that statement.  We begin with a base case, $k=1$ and show that it is true for that.  We assume it to be true for *some* $k\geq 1$ (which is true since we already checked the case when $k=1$), and we show that it follows that is also true for $k+1$.  So, it is true for $k=1\Rightarrow$ it is true for $k=2\Rightarrow$ it is true for $k=3\Rightarrow\dots$

Comment: The reason why we can't say $(bab^{-1})^k=b^ka^kb^{-k}$ is because there is no guarantee that the group is *abelian* (commutative).  If it turns out that it is *not* abelian, then $b^2a^2b^{-2}\neq ba^2b^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the majority of the argument, with a presumed typo, so the rest becomes trying to write it with proper grammar and structure.

> Claim: $(bab^{-1})^n = ba^n b^{-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Base case: let $n=1$.  Then $(bab^{-1})^1 = bab^{-1}$

Assume for our induction hypothesis that $(bab^{-1})^n = ba^n b^{-1}$ for some $n\geq 1$.

We show then that it must also be true for $n+1$.

$(bab^{-1})^{n+1} = (bab^{-1})^n(bab^{-1}) =^{I.H.} ba^nb^{-1}bab^{-1}$

$=ba^n(b^{-1}b)ab^{-1} = ba^n 1 a b^{-1} = ba^nab^{-1}=ba^{n+1}b^{-1}$

Thus, proving the claim.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The inductive step arises by scaling both sides by $\,bab^{-1}$ then removing  $\,bb^{-1}$ on RHS.